# How do I change where a pointer points by passing it by reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, heapsort

I am trying to resize a heap object so that the program can continue if the user tries to build a heap that exceeds heap capacity. I am able to return a pointer that points to the new heap, but this does not work well with the other parts of my program. I would like to directly change where my pointer `p` points to. Here is my attempt to do so. It compiles but the pointer still points to the old location. Please help me fix this code so that I don't have to return a pointer from my `BuildHeap` function. I would post all of my code, but this is homework and I would not want my work copied.

```
HEAP* Initialize(int n) {
    HEAP* p;
    p = new HEAP;
    p->size = 0;
    p->capacity = n; 
    p->H = new ELEMENT[p->capacity+1]; //first address not used, so we need +1 here
    return p;
}

void Resize(int n, HEAP*& ptr) { //pass pointer by reference
    ptr = Initialize(n);
}

void BuildHeap(HEAP* p, ELEMENT *A) {
    int length = A[0].key;      //length = array size stored in A[0]
    if(length <= p->capacity) {
        p->size = length;
        for(int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
            p->H[i].key = A[i].key; //copy ELEMENT array into heap object's H array
        }
        for(int i = (length) / 2; i >= 1; i--) 
            MaxHeapify(p, i);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error: Heap capacity exceeded. Resizing heap.\n";
        Resize(length, p); //initialize a new, larger heap
        BuildHeap(p, A);
        cout << "Heap built with new heap capacity of " << p->capacity << ".\n";
    }
}
```

Edit: I was able to resolve my issue by checking if the pointer needed to be changed before even calling BuildHeap:

```
if(length > p->capacity) { //resize heap if capacity is exceeded
    cout << "Error: Heap capacity exceeded. Resizing heap.\n";
    p = Initialize(length);
}
BuildHeap(p, A);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are only using a reference to the pointer in one place, but not in others. Look at the signature of `BuildHeap`:

```
void BuildHeap(HEAP* p, ELEMENT *A)
```

Here, when you call `BuildHeap`, a copy of the pointer passed as the first argument `p` is made. Your subsequent call to `Resize` modifies that copy, but the caller of `BuildHeap` still has its own, unmodified pointer. You might want to change the signature of `BuildHeap` (and possibly other methods) to use references as well:

```
void BuildHeap(HEAP*& p, ELEMENT *A)
```

That said, you might want to consider using a class where you use a pointer which is a member variable so you don't have to pass it around all the time manually.

Comment: The caller of BuildHeap does not save any type of return yet the heap does get modified. That was the reason I used pointers to begin with. If it only has a copy, how does the heap get built when it does not exceed capacity?

Comment: @Johnny I'm not sure I can follow your train of thoughts, especially given that you don't want to show the rest of your code. Some things make no sense to me, like "save any type of return". Also, your reason to use pointers and the way you are handling them looks weird, but again it's hard to give any better advice without seeing more code.

Comment: I mean that the function returns void, yet still modifies the heap. Before I implemented pointers, the only way I could access the heap and sort it was to return a HEAP object. Now I want to take it one step further and resize the heap if needed without returning a pointer (i.e. modify the pointer). I have been able to do this it as before by returning a pointer when the function is called from main, but this is not ideal. I think the issue is that I'm trying to modify the pointer itself, not data where the pointer is pointing, which is a different set of circumstances than before. Thanks.

Comment: I realized that before BuildHeap is even called, I can determine if the pointer needs to be modified and do it from main. Thank you for your help.